# How to plot linear fits for multiple plots in one graph?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to plot linear best fit lines for the three plots in the same graph, with their respective slopes and intercepts; I don't know how to do this so they're all in the same graph along my data. Does anyone know how to do this?
I attached an image of how the graph looks below.

```
CSVfile_1 = 'Gas01_Fast.csv'
V_1, T_1, P_1, t_1 = getVTPt(filename='Gas01_Fast.csv')

CSVfile_2 = 'Gas02_Fast.csv'
V_2, T_2, P_2, t_2 = getVTPt(filename='Gas02_Fast.csv')

CSVfile_3 = 'Gas03_Fast.csv'
V_3, T_3, P_3, t_3 = getVTPt(filename='Gas03_Fast.csv')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlabel("Log(Volume)")
ax.set_ylabel("Log(Pressure)")
ax.set_title("Log(Pressure) vs Log(Volume)")


ax.errorbar(x=np.log10(V_1),y=np.log10(P_1),xerr=0,yerr=0,fmt='ro', ms=3)

ax.errorbar(x=np.log10(V_2),y=np.log10(P_2),xerr=0,yerr=0, fmt='bo', ms=3)

ax.errorbar(x=np.log10(V_3),y=np.log10(P_3),xerr=0,yerr=0, fmt='go', ms=3)

plt.legend(["Gas01_Fast.csv", "Gas02_Fast.csv","Gas03_Fast.csv"])

plt.show()
```

[image: Image of graph made by code above]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify xerr and yerr that are different from 0.
Those specify how long you want the error bar size along the x and y axis to be.

You also don't have to use subplots and ax but rather you can call errorbar directly on plt just like in the example here:

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/errorbar_limits_simple.html